# How to access a dynamic value from JavaScript to Php

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to used the value of the *centerId* and pass it to my php variable?

```
const data = {
        action: 'ft-add-member',
        maritalStatus: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-marital-status ul li.current a').data('dropdown'),
        biological: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-biological .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
        caregiver: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-caregiver .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
        whangai: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-whangai .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
        deceased: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-deceased .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
        ex: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-ex-partner.unhide .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
        relationship,
        relatedTo: familyTree.selectedPerson.relatedTo,
        centerId: familyTree._person.id,
    };
```

Comment: Javascript is processed in the browser (Client side in this case), PHP runs on the server. To send something from the client to the server you have to use POST. In your case, you probably want to do this with AJAX, but the older method of setting a form action to POST works fine too.

Comment: You wouldn't pass it to a PHP variable because by that point PHP had already executed. Do you mean send it to your server through ajax? Then your PHP could pick it up

Comment: that means I need to bridge it with the post method via ajax? correct me if im wrong. just new to js ajax and php.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send that data through AJAX to a PHP endpoint.

**Javascript:**

```js
const data = {
  action: 'ft-add-member',
  maritalStatus: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-marital-status ul li.current a').data('dropdown'),
  biological: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-biological .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
  caregiver: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-caregiver .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
  whangai: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-whangai .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
  deceased: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-deceased .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
  ex: $('.ft-entry-relationship-info .ft-ex-partner.unhide .ft-circle-check').hasClass('checked'),
  relationship,
  relatedTo: familyTree.selectedPerson.relatedTo,
  centerId: familyTree._person.id,
};

fetch('/your-php-endpoint.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

**your-php-endpoint.php**:

```php
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data); // print to debug
```